# Minimizing SpringLdap dependencies

Tags: spring, maven-2, spring-ldap

I would like to use SpringLDAP to do some simple username/password verification for authentication purposes. WHile the actual jar file is quite small (less than 1 meg) it seems to have a lot of dependencies as listed by [link text](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.ldap/spring-ldap-integration-tests/1.3.0.RELEASE).

By alot i mean it seems to suck in over 50 things many which dont seem right such as spring-jdbc as I dont want any jdbc and only the ldap template class and its bare dependencies. Without wasting too much time is it possible to the spring-ldap with only a bare minimum number of dependencies which amount to something like:

- spring core
- spring ldap
- whatever logging deps they require.
- spring tx

I dont see or appreciate why the rest of thes tuff is reuqired and was wondering can anyone verify they arent really needed in the end if one sticks to the basics. The other stuff i am referring too include:

- spring-orm   // no jdbc
- beans        // i dont want ioc.
- spring-aop    // no need for aop.

I intend to wire up the beans i will be using manually. I dont want more crap in there for what ammounts to setting a few properties, and want confirmation that I dont need what is probably there just to do the ioc stuff when all i want is the ldap stuff.

Comment: So just package the dependencies that it needs to get the job done - try it with none, then keep adding the ones it needs when it fails.

Comment: Thats what im trying to avoid. The only problem with Spring is that its got too many dependencies and makes it hard to keep things simple and small.

Comment: @mP: Spring has very few mandatory dependencies, and a lot of optional ones. You need to find the ones you need, and ignore the rest.

Comment: Iknow I can start with the bare minim spring-core, clogging, spring-ldap and I might be lucky. So why does the maven repo list think it needs jdbc, orm etc. There is no reason why it should and incl those. If you wanted orm then ofvourse the depa would increase but as a start thras wrong.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that we are guessing what we need. It assumes that our tests etc cover enough and can /will fail if a different path occurs I'm prod that triggers a dep that we forgot/ were not aware of earlier.

Comment: https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-ldap/trunk/readme.txt

3. DISTRIBUTION JAR FILES

The following distinct jar files are included in the distribution. This list
specifies the respective contents and third-party dependencies.

* spring-ldap-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- Contents: The Spring LDAP library
- Dependencies: Commons Logging, Commons Lang, Commons Pool, spring-beans,
                spring-core, spring-context, spring-jdbc, spring-tx, ldapbp

Comment: * spring-ldap-test-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
- Contents: Support classes that helps LDAP with integration testing.
- Dependencies: Commons Logging, Commons Lang, Commons Pool, spring-beans,
                spring-core, spring-context, spring-jdbc, spring-tx, ldapbp

Comment: Hmm, you didn't mention Maven before now. If the Maven repo is dictating dependencies, that's an issue with maven, not Spring.

Comment: My point being that spring source themselves are theones preparing this list of deps.Its just nuts that soo much gets sucked in and i dont want to play guess the needed jars.

Answer (score 1):

At lot of the things that are sucked in are transitive dependencies - dependencies of the things that spring-ldap relies upon.  You can explicity exclude these when declaring your dependencies using the [exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) tag in the dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- other exclusions here -->
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```